# Call function from service ot pipe in Angular template?

Tags: angular

Inside template I try to assign a new CSS class:

```
 <div [class.oneChildEnabledatleast]="treeService.atLeastEnabled(node)"></div>
```

Should I use pipe instead calling service method directly from template?

The method `treeService.atLeastEnabled(node)` iterates over all tree from current node and looking for at least one enabled node.

how does it affect performance?

Comment: I'd recommend creating a simple example on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular) because as-is there isn't enough information to answer your question.

Comment: I updated question, not is it more clear